# Incorrect positioning of background image - swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using an image in the background of the application. This image is displayed correctly in one clip, while the other clip is positioned incorrectly. In the correct picture(fig .1), the background image is positioned up to Tabbar. As you can see in the wrong picture(fig .2), the background is not positioned up to Tabbar and the logo is left behind Tabbar. The codes are in the same state, but the picture is incorrectly positioned in Fig .2.

[image: Image1(correct)MAINTABLEVIEWCONTROLLER]
[image: Image2(ıncorrect)DEVICETABLEVIEWCONTROLLER]

**MainTableViewController Class**

```
class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        appThemeSetBySettingsPreference()
    }

 func appThemeSetBySettingsPreference() {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
            UIImage(named: "...png")?.draw(in: view.bounds)

            if let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(){
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)

            }
 }
}
```

**DeviceViewController Class**

```
  class DeviceViewController: UITableViewController

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        appThemeSetBySettingsPreference()
    }

 func appThemeSetBySettingsPreference() {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
            UIImage(named: "...png")?.draw(in: view.bounds)

            if let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(){
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)

            }
 }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
  let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(contentsOfFile:"...."));

            let tabBarHeight = tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height

            let topBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height + (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0)
            image.frame = CGRect(x:0 , y: topBarHeight, width: self.view.frame.size.width , height: self.view.frame.size.height - topBarHeight - tabBarHeight!)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the iPhone X, the height of the top bar (navigation bar + status bar) is changed. So you can get exact height of the top bar (both navigation bars + status bar):

Swift 4:

```
let topBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height  +(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0)
```

Swift 3:

```
let topBarHeight = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height + (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0)
```

Objective-C:

```
CGFloat topbarHeight = ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height  + (self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height ?: 0.0));
```

And the height of the tab bar can be obtained as follows

```
let tabBarHeight = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height ?? 49.0
```

Having these values ​​you can adapt your image to when starting your controller in your method viewDidLoad() of your class, for example

```
self.image.frame = CGRect(x:0 , y: topBarHeight, width: self.view.frame.size.width , height: self.view.frame.size.height - topBarHeight - tabBarHeight)
```

Comment: I changed the code in the way in the topic, but I get a null error in the tabBarHeight section. Thanks

Comment: try like this let tabBarHeight = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height ?? 49.0